# Compositing an animation

Tags: animation, compositing-nodes

I've rendered an animation in two series of images, with different lighting, and I wish to use the compositor to produce from these series of images the frames to be used in video sequencing. The image series have been selected to Image nodes and the output of compositing is plugged to a File Output node, with the directory for file output assigned.

How do you execute the writing of image files when compositing an image sequence? When I press Animation or Render in the Render Panel, it gives the error message "No camera found in scene".

Comment: Compositor can't work without active renderlayer. Just add a dummy one without objects, except camera.

Comment: A dummy render layer solved that problem. There is another issue- the compositor puts out pink images after about 20 frames have been composited and saved. I had rendered to Multilayer EXR and the files are quite large- the whole batch of EXRs is about 8 GB. Is this caused by overuse of RAM? Do the Cyclic and Auto-Refresh selections on the Image nodes have any effect on this behavior? I use CPU rendering and my computer with 16 GB RAM doesn't use a high level of RAM during the compositing work, so can there be a bottleneck in rendering settings or Blender's user preferences settings?

Comment: Pink color means that actual image is missing. Also Multilayer EXR's are buggy (they sometimes bring so much pain in work, like changing layer order during animation). Anyway, you should check Auto-Refresh and manually look through every layer in problem frames to be sure EXR provide right data.